# Displaying the database in a list in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to display the database in a list in Android. I am using cursors for that. I am getting the columncount and using `for` loop I am moving the cursor. But the database is not displayed. Please help. Here is my code:

```
List<String> s;
Cursor c = db.query(Geo_Create_Table, new String[] { lat + "", lon + "", result1 }, null, null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
int count = c.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other simpler approach.

Comment: this code cycles through your rows (`c.moveToNext()`) using the count from your columns, are you sure this is what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have lost some of your code there. You should edit your post, I don't have the privilages. The column count will give you the number of columns (fields) in each row and shouldn't be used to loop through the cursor's records if that is what you're trying to do, you should probably use the `getCount()` method instead.

```
List<String> s;
Cursor c=db.query(Geo_Create_Table, new String[]{lat+"",lon+"",result1}, null,null, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
int count=c.getCount();
for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    ....
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Alternatively, in my code below you query moveToFirst(), if this returns true it means there are records to be traversed. The I use a do/while loop to move through each record (note: c.moveToNext()).

```
List s; 
Cursor c=db.query(Geo_Create_Table, new String[]{lat+"",lon+"",result1}, null,null, null, null, null); 
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do
    {
        ...
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    while (!c.isAfterLast());
}
```

Comment: You'll need to create an activity that will display those records for you.

Comment: ya i am trying that but the intent method is not working in the button listener pls help pls paste the code or some article link

Comment: Okay. Post the code for your button listener with the intent method.